# How to get an APK into the market with an extra certificate... because I lost my first keystore

Tags: android, keystore

My keystore has gone missing. I most likely deleted it by mistake, but I can't find it in my recycling bin.
My keystore was originally in my bin folder, not a good place for it as files get automatically deleted when publishing

I know the details for the previous keystore. except maybe the date of expiry.

I want to put an update onto the market, but because the new certificate is different, it won't let me.

I was hoping that I could add an additional certificate to the current published file so that it would accept the updated version with just the new certificate. Similar to what is described here. [How to sign an APK with more than one certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate)

I skip the first line in the above description because it is already signed through eclipse, but when I do the second line I get a ZipException due to "invalid entry compressed size (expected X but got Y bytes)"

Is there a way to put a second certificate on my apk?

Is there a way to recreate the original keystore from the information I know?

I'm not yet ready to believe, that I will have to submit the update as a completely new application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've lost the private key then you'll be unable to recover it and sign future versions of your app.

The certificate fields are just text. The thing that actually proves your identity as the developer is the private key, which is basically a random sequence of bits.

Comment: ... so I can't sign it with an additional certificate to get around the "The apk must be signed with at least one certificate in common with the previous version." issue then?

Comment: You might be able to sign the current version with a new key also, but you'll still be stuck after that, as your users will have to remove and readd the app to receive any future upgrades.

Comment: I don't mind the users having to remove and readd the app, I'm more concerned about losing the ratings and the download stats.

Comment: I was able to unzip the existing apk and then repackage / sign it, but then the Market needed the Manifest version to be greater than the current version... i realised the inevitable and created a new app on the market.

Answer (score 5):

you are screwed.