# How can I specify a custom APK filename when publishing a MAUI app?

Tags: android, apk, maui, dotnet-publish

When [publishing a MAUI app for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0#publish), I can either use

```xml
<IpaPackageName>IPA.ipa</IpaPackageName>
```

in the project file or add `-p:IpaPackageName=IPA.ipa` to the `dotnet publish` command to change the filename of the distribution package. I didn't find much documentation but it's obvious once you change it in the project properties:

[image]

What is the equivalent setting for Android? I can't find a way in the UI to change the APK filename.

Comment: 1. Right click your app -->`Properties`; 2. Switch to tab `Android` - `Manifest`; 3. You will see the Application package name just as follows, then you can modify the name of it.

Comment: Yes, but that changes the application identifier as well, and I want that to remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio

1.Go to project `Properties` by right clicking the android project; Switch to tab `Android` - `Manifest`; You will see the Application package name just as follows, then you can modify the name of it.

2.Go to Android Manifest.

You said that changes the application identifier as well. It seems to be the default setting. About it, you can refer to [Configure the app module](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module).

Some relevant cases about "change the package name", you can check [Is it possible to change the package name of an Android app on Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582289/is-it-possible-to-change-the-package-name-of-an-android-app-on-google-play) and [Changing the package name of an upgraded Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612211/changing-the-package-name-of-an-upgraded-android-application)