# is it possible release an updated app by signing it with a different certificate than the one originally used

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

Is it possible to release an update of an android app by signing it with a different certificate than the one originally used? I know it gives an error message normally when we try to upload such a build to the market. But is there any way out, like marking it as a major release, specifying somewhere in the market place?

Comment: Nice question. I am also interested

Comment: No, i didn't find any other than using different app-ids for major release vs beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not do it. The certificate is a tool to ensure you're the one who firstly uploaded the application.

So always backup the keystore!

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, but it should be possible in the future when this issue get's resolved:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30870

Be clear though, that it's absolutely no excuse for loosing your keystore. It would just allow old keys to be renewed for security, and allow apps to move domains or change ownership.

Edit: I didn't think this was possible, but I just found this:

[How to sign an APK with more than one certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate)

Awesome!