# change certificate in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the certificate for an apk? 
 My problem is, that I have got the certificate of a developer which leaves the company and he use it's own. I try to give the apk two certificate, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate), but i can't update the old one.

 on my research I also found [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/technical-help/nc6IJV8imlI)

Comment: maybe this can help, this apk is not in the Marked but our customers Update this apk by install the newest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have published your application to Google Play, then, sorry, you can't change certificate for it. You can only publish it as different app now (different package name as well). Google explicitly states that as in docs so in IO presentations.

Comment: i've don't published it in Google Play, but for the user i just want to reinstall it by updating.

Comment: No way as well. It will just be complaining that APK signatures don't match. This is just how it works. What I would do is to try implement some transparent data transfer between old and new apps and tell users to use new one. But you know... human factor...

Comment: I also got the idear with another aplication but like you say, human factor :-) but i think i have to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

Apks of same application(i.e different version of app )must always be signed with the same certificate/key.Else will be treated as different app

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843261/1075066) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketupgrade)