# Android - What happens when a signing key expires?

Tags: android, apk, code-signing, android-install-apk, code-signing-certificate

If a signing key expires, do existing apks refuse to install, or does it just mean that new apps can't be signed with that key?

We are recommended to use keys that expire in 25+ years, and Google Play *mandates* expiry of at least 2033-10-22! However, some people may wish to [renew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate) their keys *far* more frequently than that for security reasons (Moore's law, cracked algorthms, etc.).

If an apk's key has expired, is there any way of installing it (without relying on the developer to re-release)?

Comment: Note to anyone about to answer: I have now answered my own question in full. I will post it when the 8 hour timer for new users runs out...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is going to happen when the first Android keystore certificates expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259955/what-is-going-to-happen-when-the-first-android-keystore-certificates-expire)

Answer (score 6):

> If a signing key expires, do existing apks refuse to install, or does it just mean that new apps can't be signed with that key?

`jarsigner` will refuse to use an expired key, and apk's signed with the old key will be refused by Android on install, but apps already installed will continue to run just fine.

https://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

> If an apk's key has expired, is there any way of installing it (without relying on the developer to re-release)?

Yes, the apk can be [resigned with your own certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-resign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with).

Comment: It can be resigned but not uploaded to Google Playstore. It has to have the original certificate.