# I used debug.keystore to upload my app

Tags: android, certificate, signing

I uploaded my first APP using the debug.keystore (rookie mistake). But now I have read that the certificate is valid only for 365, so my questions is. Once the 365 finished, I could not upload new versions of my app?

Comment: You might like https://stackoverflow.com/q/10566884/3166697

Comment: Hi Dima. But about the explanetion in the other link, once this debug.keystore certified expire, then I could generate a new owncertified and sing my already uploaded up with the new one?

Comment: You should create a new app(with a new name of the package) and sign it with a new key to upload the app to Google Play

Comment: So, once the certificate expire, I will lost my app?

Comment: You can't upload updates of your app with expired key(s)