# The apk must be signed with the same certificates

Tags: android, google-play

When i try to uploading new update of my app, gives me this error "The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version".
Procedure:
I use export wizard from eclipse, than load old cert file from my folder, i enter password correctly (i test it to enter incorrect, and cant go further) so i know for shure that is correct, and for alias the correct pass to, and save the apk. When i try to upload gives me the error. The package is the same, and oll the stuff.
Can anyone tell me where is the problem ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's the same cert? Because if you lost the original certificate it's over.

Comment: Yes 100 %, I allways save the cert file in specific folder

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely your certificates are different, you may check using the following commands:

```
unzip -d tmp filename.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA
keytool -printcert -v -file tmp/META-INF/CERT.RSA
```

where `filename.apk` is you apk for current and/or previous version.

Answer (score 0):

One of three things could cause this problem:

1. Using a different private key cert (sounds like you don't think this is your problem)
2. Not increasing the versionCode and versionName in android manifest
3. Using a different package name

Hopefully it's not that you lost the cert!  Good luck!  Someone mentioned that it is possible to sign an old version of your app with multiple certs, and then continue to use the one you still have like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate)

Comment: @om3trix even for the first update you must have 2 certs, debug and release.

Comment: Sorry, i'm little confused "debug and release" ? If you are saying Keystore Selection and Key alias selection ? I entered correctly pass, because if you dont typed correctly you cant go to next step. I was trying to post some images here, but as a new user i can't :(

Comment: By curiosity, i have 4 apps with 4 different certs, and with different passwords. Can that be a problem. Do i need to have one cert for all apps or not ?

Comment: This is what the official docs say, but it seems like it should work with all different certs, just not recomended http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies

Comment: Honestly I really do feel like this has happened to me before though...try cleaning the project, quitting eclipse, re-open and try again

Comment: I just tryed with my 2 other apps, SAME procedure and no problem at all. I think i have to quit in this one!