# I delete the keystore

Tags: android, apk, google-play, sha1, keystore

I want to update my app in the Google Play but this message opened.
I deleted my keystore.
What I can do for update the apk?

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

> [ SHA1: 30:36:E4:D2:CE:4F:3A:C9:66:93:EF:BB:67:B0:77:7A:6A:78:57:B6 ]
>   and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have
>   fingerprint(s): [ SHA1:
>   0F:91:AD:5A:76:D5:99:E5:F2:97:82:58:BA:16:18:75:A9:92:01:BB ]

Comment: if you are not able to restore the old keystor the only thing you can do is to load the apk as a new applicatoin

Comment: Dude, u cannot get it back but there is a possible way around see following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do unfortunately. Maybe you could try doing a system restore, on your computer, to a previous date in which you haven't misplaced or deleted your key yet.