# Motodev Studio Keystore Issue

Tags: android, keytool, motodev-studio

I developed an app some 2 or 3 years ago using the now apparently defunct Motodev Studio.  I saved the keystore file, but the java keytool does not seem to recognize the file:

```
>keystore -list -keystore motodev.keystore
```

returns

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

It would be really nice to be able to use this keystore, since I have literally tens of thousands of current installs on the app it controls.

Comment: Are you sure that your keystore file is not corrupt somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was the PM on MOTODEV Studio. The cert was in a different format than what ADT uses (long story).  I believe the storage formats were either JKS (the standard Java keystore), JCEKS (a Java keystore that provides much stronger protection of private keys), or PKCS12.

It might be possible to use with jarsigner directly with

`jarsigner -storetype JKS -keystore file:my_motodev_keystore.key`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html

I'll ping a couple of the engineers who were on the project and see if they can shed some light on how to convert that format into something jarsigner can use.

**EDIT:** One of the guys sent me this note...

[How to sign an APK with more than one certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate)

Second answer. It says how to convert the motodev keystore to jks by runing the following command:

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore motodev.keystore -srckeystoretype JCEKS -destkeystore android.keystore -destkeystoretype JKS`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I appreciate it.  I guess I should probably note that I ended up figuring out that the keystore format was JCEKS pretty much by chance after going through the possibilities in the Java 1.6 documentation.  After that it was pretty easy to use jarsigner at the command line.