# APK update when using different certificates

Tags: android, code-signing

I understand that an APK can be signed [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881904/how-to-sign-an-apk-with-more-than-one-certificate) using jarsigner. Also, all updates should be signed with the [same key](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#considerations). Assume an APK was signed with three certificates, is it a hard requirement that all updates MUST be signed with all three certificates? Or, is it okay with PackageManager if an update is signed with just one of the three certificates?

Comment: try it out,  create an unsigned apk,  sign it three times, zipalign it, and install on device via `adb install nameo.apk`.  Then bump the versioncode in the manifest. create another unsigned apk, sign that three times, and zipalign it.  Then install via `adb install -r nameo.apk`

Answer (score 0):

PackageManager checks to ensure that all updates are signed with the same key(s).

adb install -r  
1380 KB/s (1107561 bytes in 0.783s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release-unsigned.apk
**Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]​**

1. I created two keystores Signed version 1 with just one keystore
2. Bumped up the version to 2
3. Signed the APK with two keys
4. At install
           time, Android gave the above error

​Also, Google Play does not allow uploading APKs that are signed with more than one key. 
[image]