# Can I sign my android app with multi certificates?

Tags: android

Someone gave me an android app signed with a debug certificate, I've published this app but I regret. Now I want to upgrade the app and add a release certificate as well as the ancient debug certificate.Is that possible? If possible, can I remove the debug certificate and keep only the release one in the next version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. You need to republish as a new App if you plan to sign with different certificate, As stated in

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

> If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which
>   you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to
>   your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the
>   same key.

Comment: What's the sense of multi-certificates? If the app is signed with two certificates, we can only update the app using both the same certificates?

Comment: You could multi sign your APK, but you can't publish it to googleplay. Refers to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2883981/3286489